# Why is the Keyspace of a Substitution Cipher not 2^26 but 2^88

Tags: encryption, cryptography

It is known that a cipher has a key space of cryptographic algorithm is whose key length is n is given by 2^n. 
But the key space of the substitution cipher is 2^88 which is an approximation of 26!. (I am considering a alphabet of 26 letters)

Assuming the key length is 26 (which it should be for the alphabet) Why is it not 2^26?

Comment: This should be closed; you have asked this on crypto.stackexchange and is off topic for SO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about programming.

Comment: cross posted to: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76905/72896

Answer (score 3):

> Assuming the key length is 26 (which it should be for the alphabet) Why is it not 2^26?

Because there aren't `2` choices for each of the `26` elements of the key.

There are `26`... `A-Z`.

For binary based keys we only have a choice of `1` or `0` for each element in the key.

So that's where the `2` in the `2^n` comes from.

For letters, we have `26` possibilities, and as you stipulate, `26` elements for key length.

i.e. it's `26^26` possible permutations of key, for a key length `26`, with `26` possible characters.

=== `6156119580207157310796674288400203776`

This all assumes that we are allowed use the same letter multiple times in the key. If not it becomes `26*25*24...`